# Where does my PHP code make connection to the database?

Tags: php, mongodb, connection-string

So I am very new to MongoDB and PHP and I am trying to make a connection to the database and perform an insert query on it. I have managed to make it work, but know I do not really understand my own code.

**My code:**

```
<?php
   // PHP version 7.4 used here
    try {
        require 'mongophp/vendor/autoload.php';
        //$mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
        echo "Connection to database successfully\n";

        $collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->shinto->users;
        $insertOneResult = $collection->insertOne([
            "name" => "testuser", 
            "password" => "1234",
        ]);

        printf("Inserted %d document(s)\n", $insertOneResult->getInsertedCount());

        var_dump($insertOneResult->getInsertedId());

        echo "so far so good";
    }
    catch (Throwable $e) {
        // catch throwables when the connection is not a success
        echo "Captured Throwable for connection : " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        print("\ndoes not work\n");
    }
?>
```

The thing that I do not understand is how the code knows where my database is since I do not have to use the connection string.
My guess is that the mongophp/vendor/autoload.php takes care of this part, but I have looked through those files and can't seem to find the answer to my question in there as well.

Can someone help me understand how my code knows where my database is without a connection string or provide me with a link that will explain this to me?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It’s probably assuming the default port on the local machine, which happens to be correct in this case. YMMV in other environments.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the fast reply! Would you perhaps know how my code should look if it is not on the default port?

Comment: Pass a connection string to `new MongoDB\Client`…‽

Comment: Ahh that sounds logical. Thanks again!

Comment: Pass a connection string to `new MongoDB\Client()` Your code works only, because `'mongodb://localhost:27017'` is the default. As soon as you use authentication (which you should do **always**), or run MongoDB at different host or port, then your code will fail.